# Could not cast or convert from {null} to system.Int32 in JSON response C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, json, visual-studio-2010

I'm getting the following exception when using this bit of code to deserialize a JSON response from CrunchBase. The weird thing is it only happens to certain pages that are being deserialized even though both the results that work fine and the ones that don't both have empty [], empty"", and null values in key:value pairs. How can I cast or correct my mistake?

Exception gets thrown here:

```
   JsonSerializer serializer = new JsonSerializer();
   RootObject ro = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(response);
```

The inner exception is:

```
   InnerException: 
   Message=Could not cast or convert from {null} to System.Int32.
   Source=Newtonsoft.Json
```

Thanks for your eyes in advance!

Update:
as asked for the structure of the root object and the additional objects on that JSON endpoint. These were generated by http://json2csharp.com/ after putting the URL of the JSON endpoint into it.

The JSON is long so here are two example links: this one works without error http://api.crunchbase.com/v/1/company/kiip.js , while this other (and others) throws the exception http://api.crunchbase.com/v/1/company/tata-communications.js

```
      public class Image
    {
        public List<List<object>> available_sizes { get; set; }
        public object attribution { get; set; }
    }

    public class Person
    {
        public string first_name { get; set; }
        public string last_name { get; set; }
        public string permalink { get; set; }
    }

    public class Relationship
    {
        public bool is_past { get; set; }
        public string title { get; set; }
        public Person person { get; set; }
    }

    public class Provider
    {
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string permalink { get; set; }
    }

    public class Providership
    {
        public string title { get; set; }
        public bool is_past { get; set; }
        public Provider provider { get; set; }
    }

    public class FinancialOrg
    {
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string permalink { get; set; }
    }

    public class Person2
    {
        public string first_name { get; set; }
        public string last_name { get; set; }
        public string permalink { get; set; }
    }

    public class Investment
    {
        public object company { get; set; }
        public FinancialOrg financial_org { get; set; }
        public Person2 person { get; set; }
    }

    public class FundingRound
    {
        public string round_code { get; set; }
        public string source_url { get; set; }
        public string source_description { get; set; }
        public double raised_amount { get; set; }
        public string raised_currency_code { get; set; }
        public int funded_year { get; set; }
        public int funded_month { get; set; }
        public int funded_day { get; set; }
        public List<Investment> investments { get; set; }
    }

    public class Office
    {
        public string description { get; set; }
        public string address1 { get; set; }
        public string address2 { get; set; }
        public string zip_code { get; set; }
        public string city { get; set; }
        public string state_code { get; set; }
        public string country_code { get; set; }
        public object latitude { get; set; }
        public object longitude { get; set; }
    }

    public class VideoEmbed
    {
        public string embed_code { get; set; }
        public string description { get; set; }
    }

    public class Screenshot
    {
        public List<List<object>> available_sizes { get; set; }
        public object attribution { get; set; }
    }

    public class RootObject
    {
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string permalink { get; set; }
        public string crunchbase_url { get; set; }
        public string homepage_url { get; set; }
        public string blog_url { get; set; }
        public string blog_feed_url { get; set; }
        public string twitter_username { get; set; }
        public string category_code { get; set; }
        public int number_of_employees { get; set; }
        public int founded_year { get; set; }
        public int founded_month { get; set; }
        public object founded_day { get; set; }
        public object deadpooled_year { get; set; }
        public object deadpooled_month { get; set; }
        public object deadpooled_day { get; set; }
        public object deadpooled_url { get; set; }
        public string tag_list { get; set; }
        public string alias_list { get; set; }
        public string email_address { get; set; }
        public string phone_number { get; set; }
        public string description { get; set; }
        public string created_at { get; set; }
        public string updated_at { get; set; }
        public string overview { get; set; }
        public Image image { get; set; }
        public List<object> products { get; set; }
        public List<Relationship> relationships { get; set; }
        public List<object> competitions { get; set; }
        public List<Providership> providerships { get; set; }
        public string total_money_raised { get; set; }
        public List<FundingRound> funding_rounds { get; set; }
        public List<object> investments { get; set; }
        public object acquisition { get; set; }
        public List<object> acquisitions { get; set; }
        public List<Office> offices { get; set; }
        public List<object> milestones { get; set; }
        public object ipo { get; set; }
        public List<VideoEmbed> video_embeds { get; set; }
        public List<Screenshot> screenshots { get; set; }
        public List<object> external_links { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Can you change your `System.Int32` to `Nullable<System.Int32>` and try?

Comment: Can you give us some more info? The structure of RootObject or perhaps some sample JSON?

Answer (score 0):

Json.NET supports [JSON Schema](http://james.newtonking.com/archive/2009/01/04/json-net-3-5-beta-2-json-schema-validation.aspx). You could create a schema with all the required properties marked and validate incoming JSON against it before deserializing. In this you can check if value is `null` you can make change it to some default value.

Hope this works for you.

Comment: Thanks, I'm gonna try that know and let you know how it went. Thank you for your quick help! Much appreciated!

Comment: I looked into the info that you suggested, unfortunately my level of understanding has failed me in being able to grasp how to actually take advantage of this in my application. infortunately I think I need a little bit of individual help just getting up to speed, read your profile, maybe you or someone you know might be interested... please look here http://bangalore.craigslist.co.in/cpg/2812084605.html if not my appologies

Comment: @Amar Palsapure: What are appropriate values for null-values when you have keys you must use?